# Flickering on bitmap-based video player

Tags: windows, mfc

I'm trying to put together a simple video player for videos stored in RAW format. These videos are optionally passed through a convolution filter. My CWinApp class has three relevant methods. First, when a video is selected and placed in the pointer `viewingVideo`, I allocate two bitmaps:

```
void CMyApp::setBitmaps() {
    if (viewingVideo == NULL)
        return;


    bmp1 = CreateDIBSection(dc, viewingVideo->bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, NULL, NULL, 0);
    bmp2 = CreateDIBSection(dc, viewingVideo->bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, NULL, NULL, 0);
}
```

Then, when the user presses play, I initialize timers that call the following two methods ever 33 ms, for 30 fps playback:

```
void CMyApp::updateVideoFrame() {
    if (viewingVideo == NULL)
        return;

    if (viewingKernel != NULL) {
        applyKernelFFT(viewingKernel, viewingVideo, currentFrame);
    }

    if (viewingKernel == NULL)
        SetDIBits(dc, bmpToggle ? bmp2 : bmp1, 0, viewingVideo->height, (char*)(viewingVideo->data) + currentFrame*viewingVideo->bpp*viewingVideo->width*viewingVideo->height, viewingVideo->bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    else
        SetDIBits(dc, bmpToggle ? bmp2 : bmp1, 0, viewingVideo->height, (char*)(viewingVideo->filtered_data), viewingVideo->bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    bmpToggle = !bmpToggle;
}

void CMyApp::updateVideoScreen() {
    CMyView* view = CMyView::GetView(); //returns the active view
    view->m_Video.SetBitmap(bmpToggle ? bmp1 : bmp2);
    CRect update;
    view->m_Video.GetWindowRect(&update);
    view->ScreenToClient(&update);
    //update.DeflateRect(update.Width()/2-1, update.Height()/2 - 1);
    InvalidateRect(*AfxGetMainWnd(), update, FALSE);
}
```

At any given time, the methods should be using different bitmaps. There's quite a bit of flickering on the screen when I start these timers. When I uncomment the `DeflateRect` call, making `update` a 2x2 pixel rectangle, it becomes clear that there are actually two sources of flickering: sometimes the entire picture flickers, and sometimes only the 2x2 rectangle in the center.

I've tried the common fixes suggested elsewhere, like handing `WM_ERASEBKGND` in `CMyView`. This hasn't helped. How can I prevent this flickering?

Comment: And what does your WM_PAINT handler look like?

Comment: Maybe that's the issue, I'm not currently handling WM_PAINT. Do I need double buffering? If so, what's the proper way of doing that in MFC?

Comment: You're invalidating the main window in updateVideoScreen, which is going to trigger a WM_PAINT.  I assumed that's when you would actually blit the bitmap to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who wants to remove the epilepsy warning from their software, here's what it took to fix the flickering. Adrian McCarthy's suggestion was exactly right. In `updateVideoScreen`, I replaced `view->m_Video.SetBitmap(bmpToggle ? bmp1 : bmp2);` with `SelectObject(dc, bmpToggle ? bmp1 : bmp2);`, so the bitmap data is sent to my memory DC and not to the control. Then I overrode `OnPaint()` to call `BitBlt` to write the bitmap to the screen where the video control would have been:

```
void CMTFBoostView::OnPaint()
{
    CRect rect;
    m_Video.GetWindowRect(&rect);
    ScreenToClient(&rect);

    video* v = ((CMTFBoostApp*)AfxGetApp())->viewingVideo;
    CDC* src = ((CMTFBoostApp*)AfxGetApp())->cdc;

    CDC* dc = GetDC();
    if (v != NULL && dc->RectVisible(rect)) {
        dc->BitBlt(rect.left, rect.top, v->width, v->height, src, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    }
    ReleaseDC(dc);
    CFormView::OnPaint();
}
```

The first few lines are a bit of a hack to put the video where I had it before - it would probably be cleaner to remove the CStatic control from the view altogether. Regardless, this displays the video with no flickering.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a `CPaintDC` in your `OnPaint` handler?

Comment: There's no particular reason - perhaps a `CPaintDC` would be semantically more correct, or just better practice. More important is that I forgot to call `ReleaseDC(dc)`, which caused problems after displaying several thousand frames. I've edited the code with this change.

Comment: Using a `CPaintDC` is not just semantically more correct. It is functionally correct. Not using a `CPaintDC` fails to validate the invalid region, causing a constant stream of superfluous `WM_PAINT` messages to be generated. Besides that, your updated code does not compile. The call to `ReleaseDC` is outside the function body. Please don't post fake code.

Comment: Thanks for catching my typo on the `ReleaseDC`. I've tried to get this working with a `CPaintDC`, but to get the picture to update I had to change my `InvalidateRect` call, and that brings the flickering back (so it doesn't feel like an appropriate answer to this question). If you could let me know how to properly invalidate the region for use with a `CPaintDC`, I'll gladly update the answer. Otherwise, this seems to be the best I can do for now, despite the superfluous `WM_PAINT` messages.